# How to hide text using java script and show another text and whole java script code trigger by php?

Tags: javascript, php, css

`$_SESSION['MSG']="Incorrect email id and password"` is in red color.

After 5 sec it will hide and after that I want to show Try again later in yellow color at same place after 5 sec. `$_SESSION['try']="Try again later"` but it will not hide until page is not reload or refresh:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['MSG'])){
echo '<div  id="incorrect">' . $_SESSION['MSG'] .  '</div><script 
type="text/javascript">  
function showIt() {  
document.getElementById("incorrect").style.visibility = "hidden";  
}  
setTimeout("showIt()", 5000); 
</script>';
}
unset ($_SESSION['MSG']); 
session_destroy ();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['MSG'])){
    echo '<div id="incorrect">'.$_SESSION['MSG'].'</div><script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("incorrect").style.cssText = "background: red";
    function showIt() {
        document.getElementById("incorrect").style.visibility = "hidden";  
    }
    setTimeout("showIt()", 5000);
    function showIt() {
        document.getElementById("incorrect").style.cssText = "background: yellow";
        document.getElementById("incorrect").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("incorrect").innerHTML = "'.$_SESSION["try"].'";
    }
    </script>';
}
```

You use the `innerHTML` to change the message within the `<div></div>`.